MAUI: Issue with uploading project's local image to database via post API as ByteArrayContent - System.ArgumentNullException
I have added a few avatar images on the project folder named Avatars and set its Build Action to Embedded Resource.
I added it for profile image update for the user. I need to upload the selected image to our database using a POST API. Below is the code I am using:
try
{
    if (isAvatar)
    {
        string avatarFileName = "MyProjectName.Avatars." + selectedAvatar;
        var assembly = typeof(RESTServices).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{avatarFileName}");
        var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        content.Add(streamContent, "file", avatarFileName);
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AvatarException:>" + exc);
}

But I am getting the below exception:
AvatarException:>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'content')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamContent..ctor(Stream content)
   at ProjectName.RESTServices.SaveProfile(String jsonData, String applicationId, String siteId, FileResult photo, ByteArrayContent cameraByteContents, String cameraPicPath, String selectedAvatar, Boolean isGallery, Boolean isCamera, Boolean isAvatar) in E:\My Projects\MAUI
eedhelp-app-maui\ProjectName\RESTServices.cs:line 1004

The exception is on the below line:
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

The image folder is on the project's root folder. Check the below screenshot:

Is there any mistake on the path of the selected avatar image and due to that this null issue is showing?

This question is similar to: MAUI: Issue with saving an Image as a ByteArrayContent taken from camera Microsoft.Maui.Media.MediaPicker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You already asked this question.  Please do not post duplicates

@Jason Because multiple issues on a single thread. I edited previous question and made it for camera image issue only. And created this with all the details for the local image issue.

I’ll make the same comment I did on your previous question - why is content null?  Work backwards from that line to determine where the problem starts.  I’d guess that you are not correctly building the resource name correctly, but it could be something else

@Jason I tried updating the avatarFileName code with the projectname + foldername, but the image is not reading.

What is the build action of the image files?

@Jason Embedded Resource is the build action

what is the actual value of the string you are passing in for the name?

@Jason ic_avatar01_xx.png this way I named the avatar images.

That's not what I asked.  I asked you for the actual value of the string you are passing, not just the name of the image.

@Jason MyProjectName.Avatars.ic_avatar01_xx.png

Please set the image's Build Action to the MauiAsset in the Avatars folder, then read it by using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Avatars\\"+ selectedAvatar);
 using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Avatars\\"+ selectedAvatar);
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 stream.CopyTo(ms);
 ms.Position = 0;    
 StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);

 //you can detect the streamContent is not null by the length
 var length= streamContent.Headers.ContentLength;

